# NDSolve overdetermined but I can't see how

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

## Edit: partial answer

This confuses me but it is due to some behaviour of pattern matching which just seems wrong to me.

An example of the behaviour

```
g[-(15/2), t] /. {f_[-15, t_] -> (0)}
```

gives `g[0,t]`

whereas

```
g[-(15/2), t] /. {f_[-15, t] -> (0)}
```

gives, what I would expect either of them to give, `g[-(15/2), t]`

I suppose this makes sense if 15/2 is seen as something like Fraction[15,2], is there some such function?

end of edit

For various reasons I am manually discretizing a PDE to solve using the method of lines, however for some choices of the number of points NDSolve tells me my equations are overdetermined. This is despite the fact that I have, say, M variables with M ODEs and M initial data. An example (the specific PDE is not important) is below:

```
testeq={D[g[x,t],t]+g[x, t]-D[g[x,t],x]};

testdiscretize[equations_, n_, xedge_, nt_,tmax_, \[Epsilon]dissipation_] := Module[{h, \[Delta]t, tempeqs},
  h = 2 xedge/(2^n);
  \[Delta]t = tmax/(2^nt);
  tempeqs = equations /.f_[x, t] -> Table[f[-xedge + (i - 1) h, t], {i, 2, 2^n}];
  tempeqs = Table[0 == tempeqs[[i, j]] /.D[f_[x_, t], x_] -> ((1/4 (f[x - 2 h, t] - f[x + 2 h, t]) + 2 (f[x + h, t] - f[x - h, t]))/(3 h)), {i, 1, Length[tempeqs]}, {j, 1, Length[tempeqs[[i]]]}];
  tempeqs = tempeqs /. D[f_[x_, t_], t_] -> D[f[x, t], t] - \[Epsilon]dissipation /(2^6 \[Delta]t) (f[x + 3 h, t] + f[x - 3 h, t] - 6 (f[x + 2 h, t] + f[x - 2 h, t]) + 15 (f[x + h, t] + f[x - h, t]) - 20 f[x, t]);
  tempeqs = tempeqs /. f_[xedge, t_] -> (0) /. f_[-xedge, t_] -> (0) /. f_[xedge + h, t_] -> (0) /. f_[-(xedge + h), t_] -> (0) /. f_[xedge + 2 h, t_] -> (0) /. f_[-(xedge + 2 h), t_] -> (0) /. f_[xedge + 3 h, t_] -> (0) /. f_[-(xedge + 3 h), t_] -> (0);
  Flatten[tempeqs]
  ]

testsystem[equations_, n_, nt_, \[Epsilon]dissipation_, g0_, \[Sigma]g_, xe_, tmax_, t_, prec_] :=  Flatten[{(testdiscretize[equations, n, xe, nt, tmax, \[Epsilon]dissipation]), Table[g[xe (-1 + 2 /(2^n) (i - 1)), 0] ==  SetPrecision[ g0 Exp[-1/2 (xe (-1 + 2 /(2^n) (i - 1))/\[Sigma]g)^2],10 + prec], {i, 2, 2^n}]}]

testsolution[equations_, n_, nt_, \[Epsilon]dissipation_,  g0_, \[Sigma]g_, xe_, tmax_, t_, prec_] :=  NDSolve[testsystem[equations, n, nt, \[Epsilon]dissipation,  g0, \[Sigma]g, xe, tmax, t, prec], Flatten[Table[{g[xe (-1 + 2 /(2^n) (i - 1)), t]}, {i, 2, 2^n}]], {t, 0, tmax}, StartingStepSize -> tmax/(2^nt),  WorkingPrecision -> 10 + prec, Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}]
```

If one then runs

```
Print["n=3"];
testsolution[testeq, 3, 3, 1/1000, 1, 5, 100, 2, t, 0];
Print["n=4"];
testsolution[testeq, 4, 4, 1/1000, 1, 5, 100, 2, t, 0];
Print["n=5"];
testsolution[testeq, 5, 5, 1/1000, 1, 5, 100, 2, t, 0];
```

you will see that (some setting of precision aside) n=3 and n=5 run perfectly fine, but n=4 says the system is overdetermined. However one can see, by running this:

```
testsystem[testeq, 4, 4, 1/1000, 1, 5, 100, 2, t, 0];
Length[%]
Module[{xe, n},
 xe = 100;
 n = 4;
 Length[Flatten[
   Table[{g[xe (-1 + 2 /(2^n) (i - 1)), t]}, {i, 2, 2^n}]]]]
testsystem[testeq, 4, 4, 1/1000, 1, 5, 100, 2, t, 0][[16 ;; 30]]
testsystem[testeq, 4, 4, 1/1000, 1, 5, 100, 2, t, 0][[1 ;; 15]]
```

that there are 15 variables, 15 ODEs and 15 initial data.

I have found a change that removes this problem (but that I do not wish to make and I don't understand why it works).

The problem seems to stem for setting points outside the boundaries = 0, i.e. this line:

```
 tempeqs = 
       tempeqs /. f_[xedge, t_] -> (0) /. f_[-xedge, t_] -> (0) /. 
             f_[xedge + h, t_] -> (0) /. f_[-(xedge + h), t_] -> (0) /. 
           f_[xedge + 2 h, t_] -> (0) /. f_[-(xedge + 2 h), t_] -> (0) /. 
         f_[xedge + 3 h, t_] -> (0) /. f_[-(xedge + 3 h), t_] -> (0);
```

If I use an alternative formulation such that I only need to set the functions at +/- xedge to 0 instead of some points outside, it no longer has this problem.

So

```
testdiscretize[equations_, n_, xedge_, nt_, 
  tmax_, \[Epsilon]dissipation_] := Module[{h, \[Delta]t, tempeqs},
  h = 2 xedge/(2^n);
  \[Delta]t = tmax/(2^nt);
  tempeqs = 
   equations /. 
    f_[x, t] -> Table[f[-xedge + (i - 1) h, t], {i, 2, 2^n}];
  tempeqs = 
   Table[0 == tempeqs[[i, j]] /. 
     D[f_[x_, t], x_] ->
      (f[x + h, t] - f[x - h, t])/(2 h), {i, 
     1, Length[tempeqs]}, {j, 1, Length[tempeqs[[i]]]}];
  tempeqs = 
   tempeqs /. 
    D[f_[x_, t_], t_] -> 
     D[f[x, t], t] - \[Epsilon]dissipation /(
       4 \[Delta]t) (f[x + h, t] + f[x - h, t] - 2 f[x, t]);
  tempeqs = 
   tempeqs /. f_[xedge, t_] -> (0) /. f_[-xedge, t_] -> (0)(*/.f_[
  xedge+h,t_]->(0)/.f_[-(xedge+h),t_]->(0)/.f_[xedge+2h,
  t_]->(0)/.f_[-(xedge+2h),t_]->(0)/.f_[xedge+3h,
  t_]->(0)/.f_[-(xedge+3h),t_]->(0)*);
  Flatten[tempeqs]
  ]
```

will work but uncommenting the replacements at the end will break it again. Those terms should not show up anywhere in the system anyway in this case. It is also not a viable solution for my purposes. Because it is due to those replacements I am sure it is something stupid but I cannot see it.

Edit:some extra information. Changing the value of xedge changes which values of n lead to equations which NDSolve reports as overdetermined.

Comment: It is wander that your code works with some parameters.  It looks like you solve not system of ODEs, but system of PDEs, since you use `Derivative[0, 1][g][x[[i]], t]` in `testsystem`. I don't understand how `NDSolve` accepts this system.

Comment: Check out FullForm[g[-(15/2), t]].  Your pattern is matching Rational[-15,2] and replacing it with 0

Comment: I turn the PDEs into ODEs by discretizing the spatial coordinate. g[x,t] become a list like {g[-1,t], g[0,t], g[1,t]} and all spatial derivatives are turned into finite differences using a 5 point stencil for 1st order derivatives.

Comment: @CraigCarter Thanks I was at this point just wondering what the function was.